# how to pass the value of the checked box to the url wihout submit?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page which is for product filtration I wanted to get checkbox value to the URL so i can make the box check using the URL which helps me to make a link for the particular product .  The page does not have any submit button .

I have been searching with java script keyword and PHP but I could not get It.if I get the code for this It would be very much helpful for my project .

I thank everyone's efforts

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You must provide some code of what you have tried or found ..

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP GET Parameters. Look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters). Then you can [manualy set the checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery) if a particular value was found in the url.

Comment: _"You could use PHP GET Parameters"_ - Sure, but the OP doesn't know how to _set_ those params _and_ submit the form in the first place (which is the actual question: _"I wanted to get checkbox value to the URL"_).

Comment: Use this as an example: stackoverflow.com?checkbox1=true&checkbox2=false

Comment: @MohamedAshif please [read](https://www.php-einfach.de/php-tutorial/_get-und-_post/) about this so you can understand whats happening.

Comment: <?php
$fun=$_GET['fun'];
$first='one';

if($fun==$first)
{
isset($_POST['ram']);
 
}


?>


<body>
<form method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="ram" value="value1">
</form>
</body>